# Couchbase .Net SDK Attachment

Tags: couchbase

I am using couchbase database for Asp.Net application. I have never found a code to push attachments on couchbase using .Net api of couchbase.
I have found some code in android like for the same requirements but i am unable in .Net SDK.

I am using couchbase .Net SDK 2.0.
thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking? What is the question here?

Comment: Can you expand what you mean by 'push attachments'? Can you show/link to the equivalent Android (Lite SDK?) code that you're struggling to reproduce in .NET?

Comment: This is the code in android for the same problem:
/   InputStream stream = null;
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == 
        // Add or update an image to a document as a JPEG attachment:
        Document doc = database.getDocument("Robin");
        UnsavedRevision newRev = doc.getCurrentRevision().createRevision();
        newRev.setAttachment("photo.jpg", "image/jpeg", stream);
        newRev.save();
    }
}

Comment: please visit this link:
http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/attachment/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The Couchbase .NET 2.0 SDK does not support attachments like that of the Couchbase Lite/Mobile. This functionality is a carry-over from CouchDb and Couchbase Server itself does not support attachments.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the value limit on Couchbase Server is 20MB.

Comment: Could you tell me another way to achieve same challenge?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options in Couchbase to handle binary data:

1. you can serialise the binary content and and add to the document as you would any other string value
2. You can also save the "attachment" under a separate key and store the content as binary.

The benefit of option 2 is that you will not have the added overhead of the serialisation (roughly adds +30% to the size)

If you chose a smart key name strategy this can be done very elegant:

key for the main document: doc1
key for attachment: doc1::attachment::1

I hope this helps